# Add one field to specified document

Tags: sql, mongodb, database

i have few documents in mongo.

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1208600008100),
    "uwi" : "VAT",
    "num_skv" : 81,
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1067300000100),
    "uwi" : "ZM",
    "num_skv" : 1,
}
.....
```

i want add 'core' field in all documents with num_skv=1.
Which query i can use?

p.s. i want get this

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1067300000100),
    "uwi" : "ZM",
    "num_skv" : 1,
    "core" : "foo bar foor bar",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.coll.update( { num_skv: 1 }, { $set: { core: "bar" }, {multi: true} } )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.coll.update({num_skv: 1}, {$set: {core: "bar"}, {multi: true}})
```

Doc can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/)